# Why does adding "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])" cause "error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Working on a gradle project to use a new interface class inside the libs folder. Initially class A is referencing class B. Before calling:

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

it works fine and builds without issue. However once I add that command to the build.gradle for class B it starts saying class A cannot find symbol class B. Nothing else changed I simply added class C to the libs directory and called the compile command.